# Get Codeigniter "user_id" in another library outside of codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, echo

I have a user system based on codeigniter. Also, i have a calendar system based on no framework. So my question is that, how do i get the events in the calendar based on which user is logged in?

In Codeigniter i can write this line `$this->session->userdata('user_id')` and then i get which user is signed in, but since the calendar app is not codeigniter, how do i get the **"user_id"** from codeigniter to the calendar app?

Comment: explain  more please

Comment: Most probably you can. You'll need to get an instance of the session class -whatever it is in Codeigniter- and use it. As this is your first question, please  review it to ensure it's clear and descriptive, and that you include as much information as you have. Thanks.